# No answer is/was given

Tags: tense, passive-voice

> 1. No answer **is given**.
> 2. It **is given** as an example.
> 3. All items **are provided**.
> 4. It **is given as follows**.
> 5. It **is stolen property**.
> 6. Why **is present simple used** in these sentence?

It is present simple passive but it does not function as present simple passive. It sounds like it has been done, past simple.

Is it different than

> 1. b) No answer **was given**.
> 2. b) It **was given** as an example.
> 3. b) All items **were provided**.
> 4. b) It **was given as follows**.
> 5. b) It **was stolen property**.
> 6. b) Why **was Present Simple used** in these sentence?

Comment: In **these sentences** or in **this sentence**?  Which is it? And if only one sentence, then which sentence is being considered here?

Comment: Also you have an example (5/5b) that is only slightly more than an [existential clause](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_clause).  This is merely an assertion of identity with an attributive adjective. No passive voice occurs.

Comment: All these sentences show 'the status' in passive voice of present indefinite.  Voice change can reflect not the meaning, but the subject/object placement. https://sites.google.com/site/englishgrammarguide/Home/the-present-simple-tense; is a site that talks about it at the start itself.

Answer (score 0):

Though the present simple is used, in all the sentences the  part participle is working as adjective there.

> **No answer is given**
>
> **It is given as an example**
>
> **All items are provided**
>
> **It is stolen property**

Since past participle is acting like adjective in the examples, they give the impression that the activities are completed but they are not used for a particular time

If we use the simple past they talk about the completed actions

Answer (score 0):

Both present and past tenses could be correct, depending on what you mean.

In the first example, when did the lack of answer occur? To use the present tense means there is *right now* no answer. To use the past tense means there was *at that time* no answer, but an answer may (or may not) have been given since then.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between "It *is* stolen property" and "It *was* stolen property" is a subtle one. Once stolen, always stolen; the property of being (or having been) stolen property never really goes away. However, if that item is returned to the original owner, it is certainly no longer accurate to say that it *is* stolen; simply that it *was* stolen. (And for the owner to say that *it was stolen property* would be decidedly weird.)

My daughter and I have both had our bicycles stolen, but only mine was recovered. Therefore hers *is* stolen property, but mine *was* stolen property. (Thankfully an attentive LEO recognized the person riding my bike and knew that they should not be riding such a nice bike. And by "nice" I mean a bike that I bought in college, used, for $250...)

I imagine most police stations have a "Stolen Property Room". Upon entering, you might be told, "This *is* all stolen property. Everything here *was* stolen."